# Spark SQL for dividing count from two different queries and store the output as Double

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on Spark SQL using Scala. I have a requirement where I need first convert the o/p of each query to double and then divide them.This is what I tried.

Query1 -

```
scala> var noofentry = sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from bankdata")
noofentry: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [count(1): bigint]
```

Query2

```
var noofsubscribed = sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from bankdata where y='yes'")
noofsubscribed: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [count(1): bigint]
```

Now, I need to convert the output of each query to double and divide them.

```
scala > var result = noofsubscribed.head().getDouble(0) / noofentry.head().getDouble(0)
```

On doing this I've ended up with the following error.

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to 
 java.lang.Double
 at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToDouble(BoxesRunTime.java:114)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getDouble(Row.scala:248)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getDouble(rows.scala:165)... 50 elided
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are actually using count this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much as I agree with @DNA's answer, I'd like to attack this question in another way maybe considering best practice.

Doing the following is just meaningless :

```
scala> var noofentry = sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from bankdata")
```

You ought doing the following instead :

```
scala> val noofentry = sqlContext.sql("select * from bankdata").count
```

Same thing for the other query :

```
scala> val noofsubscribed = sqlContext.sql("select * from bankdata where y='yes'").count
```

now you'll just need to convert one of them :

```
scala > val result = noofsubscribed.toDouble / noofentry
```

So this is actually a code review and an answer at the same time.

Comment: I appreciate your quick response.Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome ! don't forget to accept the answer please to close the question

Comment: Does doing select count(*) from bankdata affect the performance? or Anything else

Comment: No it's just very bad practice.

Comment: You name your value "number of entry" and yet it's not. Because you'll need to call on head to fetch the first row and get the first columns

Comment: - I've got you.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a `ClassCastException` because the value in your Row is a `Long`, but you are calling `getDouble(0)` which expects a Double, as shown in the exception message:

> java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

You need to call `getLong(0)` first, then apply `toDouble` to convert the Long to Double. For example:

```
noofsubscribed.head().getLong(0).toDouble
```

Comment: I appreciate your quick response.Thanks.